# PyCharm doesn't open in 32 bits OS (Windows)

Tags: java, python, x86, pycharm

I'm in an old [laptop computer](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Asus-Transformer-Book-T100TA-C1-GR-Convertible.106219.0.html) (Windows 10 in it) which has java 1.8 version installed. I've also installed PyCharm in the computer(2017.3.2). However, when I execute it, it appears in the task manager for a while (but nothing apparently seems to open). Finally it dissapears from there.

I'd been searching in all JetBrains folders and I found out that inside PyCharm path (`C:\Users\alexc\.PyCharm2017.3`) there's only one folder (system, which is empty) while there should be (according to other users examples) two folders and inside system there should be other folders.

Anyone knows where could I download those files? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's in your installation location. Where did you install PyCharm?

Comment: @zhh It has been installed here: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3. I have to move them into C:\Users\alexc\.PyCharm2017.3?

Comment: No, you don't need to move them. In C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3\ there should be a folder named bin\, in this folder there is a 32bit version and a 64bit version.

Comment: @zhh So, I should copy the files inside the 32bit folder and copy them into the PyCharm path you've said before?

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything after installing PyCharm. Just go to the installation folder and find bin\ and choose the 32-bit version executable file.

Comment: @zhh I've tried that and doesn't work. I think It's due to the lack of the files I've mentioned before.